# wildcard link to parent route reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a class handler that would respond on both /handle and /handle/:id.
I have a problem :
The component(in this case , the handler class ) that is shown on both pages has buttons that take me from one to an other, for example a button that gets me from /handle to /handle/195 and another that gets me from /handle/195 to /handle.

So a button on /handle having:

```
onClick={()=>{hashistory.push('/handle/195')}}
```

which works perfectly, but the one on /handle/195 with:

```
onClick={()=>{hashistory.push('/handle')}}
```

does not, does anyone know how to redirect to parent URL using hashistory?
I apologize if my problem was poorly explained. I tried to do my best.

Thanks.